# Tilting backspace on Chrome or Chromium disables keyboard

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, shortcut-keys, google-chrome, chromium

In Chrome or Chromium, whenever I hold <kbd>⌫</kbd> (backspace), the keyboard shuts off.

I am able to use desktop shortcuts (<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> for first program or <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> for showing desktop), but returning back to Chrome/Chromium, the keyboard is still not functional.

I use latest Lubuntu, changing keyboard does not help.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happens to me. Apparently, if you replace iBus with Fcitx it will fix the issue. Also, if you enter `ibus restart` from command line it will make it work again.

I found this solution here [Keybord input not work in Chromium 34 Ubuntu 14.04 aura (260972) [using Fcitx would avoid this issue]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449361/keybord-input-not-work-in-chromium-34-ubuntu-14-04-aura-260972-using-fcitx-wo)

Answer (score 0):

I am using kubuntu and I've removed the libibus packet at all with all depended packets including the ibus packet itself. No any critical packages was removed, the only some unity packages which was not used anyway under kubuntu. The problem disappears.