# Ubuntu 14.10 chrome doesn't detect keyboard input

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, workspaces

When I'm using multiple workspaces, especially when I'm writing code and have every one of my workspaces occupied by some process and switch between the workspace that contains google chrome and the other ones, chrome randomly stops accepting my keyboard input.
Everytime it happens the only way to have it detect my input again is to restart it, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Seems like an iBus problem, this might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/449361/keybord-input-not-work-in-chromium-34-ubuntu-14-04-aura-260972-using-fcitx-wo https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1307648 https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=364826

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a conflict with ibus

Turning off ibus: in "Language Support" (found under Ubuntu's Preferences) switch "Keyboard input method system" from IBUS to none

[image: Language Support menu]

Comment: I don't see this anywhere in Ubuntu or Google Chrome. Whose preferences should I be looking under?

Comment: @IanHunter hope the edits help

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me :-(

Comment: It seems to require a restart as well for me.

Comment: I thought this would work for me but it didn't. Turns out I had to turn off (disable) the Intel Virtualization Technology in BIOS. After that this issue finally dissapeard on my system.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 17.10 I accidentally enabled the "slow keys" which resulted in a non reactive Chrome and VirtualBox. 
Disabling the "slow keys" did the trick on my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: kill all chrome active process with this command:

```
ps -eopid,cmd | grep -i chrome | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 2 | xargs kill
```

It happend with me today. I don't know the exatly problem but I detected that there where others chrome process alive even after I close it:

```
$ ps -eopid,cmd | grep chrome 
 3651 /opt/google/chrome/chrome http://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/
 3662 /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --enable-crash-reporter=e10f842f-2e3b-4773-9e66-7e0b7e03ff17,
 3664 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --enable-crash-reporter=e10f842f-2e3b-4773-9e66-7e0b7e03ff17,
 3666 /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox /opt/google/chrome/nacl_helper
 3668 /opt/google/chrome/nacl_helper
 3670 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --enable-crash-reporter=e10f842f-2e3b-4773-9e66-7e0b7e03ff17,
 3695 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=gpu-process --field-trial-handle=3127510087132043728,612135776437230997,131072 --enable-crash-reporter=e10f842f-2e3b-4773-9e66-7e0b7e03ff17, --gpu-preferences=KAAAAAAAAACAAACAAQAAAAAAAAAAAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAA --service-request-channel-token=14003487884351161854
 3725 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=-broker
 3741 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=3127510087132043728,612135776437230997,131072 --service-pipe-token=13853926457551779350 --lang=pt-BR --enable-crash-reporter=e10f842f-2e3b-4773-9e66-7e0b7e03ff17, --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --service-request-channel-token=13853926457551779350 --renderer-client-id=7 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100,v8_natives_data:101
 3817 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=3127510087132043728,612135776437230997,131072 --service-pipe-token=4234779571667657876 --lang=pt-BR --enable-crash-reporter=e10f842f-2e3b-4773-9e66-7e0b7e03ff17, --extension-process --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --service-request-channel-token=4234779571667657876 --renderer-client-id=3 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100,v8_natives_data:101
 3845 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=3127510087132043728,612135776437230997,131072 --service-pipe-token=14130276234297054033 --lang=pt-BR --enable-crash-reporter=e10f842f-2e3b-4773-9e66-7e0b7e03ff17, --extension-process --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --service-request-channel-token=14130276234297054033 --renderer-client-id=4 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100,v8_natives_data:101
 6106 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=3127510087132043728,612135776437230997,131072 --service-pipe-token=1105491960801759215 --lang=pt-BR --enable-crash-reporter=e10f842f-2e3b-4773-9e66-7e0b7e03ff17, --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --service-request-channel-token=1105491960801759215 --renderer-client-id=70 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100,v8_natives_data:101
 6167 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=3127510087132043728,612135776437230997,131072 --service-pipe-token=18228045149230041600 --lang=pt-BR --enable-crash-reporter=e10f842f-2e3b-4773-9e66-7e0b7e03ff17, --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --service-request-channel-token=18228045149230041600 --renderer-client-id=69 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100,v8_natives_data:101
 6180 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=3127510087132043728,612135776437230997,131072 --service-pipe-token=7644340091502831181 --lang=pt-BR --enable-crash-reporter=e10f842f-2e3b-4773-9e66-7e0b7e03ff17, --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --service-request-channel-token=7644340091502831181 --renderer-client-id=68 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100,v8_natives_data:101
 6207 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=3127510087132043728,612135776437230997,131072 --service-pipe-token=3756294107921279265 --lang=pt-BR --enable-crash-reporter=e10f842f-2e3b-4773-9e66-7e0b7e03ff17, --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --service-request-channel-token=3756294107921279265 --renderer-client-id=73 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100,v8_natives_data:101
 6228 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=3127510087132043728,612135776437230997,131072 --service-pipe-token=9129535788251446015 --lang=pt-BR --enable-crash-reporter=e10f842f-2e3b-4773-9e66-7e0b7e03ff17, --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --service-request-channel-token=9129535788251446015 --renderer-client-id=74 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100,v8_natives_data:101
 6412 grep --color=auto chrome
```

After a killed all process it started to work again.