# Google chrome, cannot type

Tags: google-chrome, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I have a problem with a Google Chrome.

When I'm switching workspaces my chrome seems to be disabled.

I cannot type on it like a keyboard doesnt work or something, I can open new page normaly (by mouse) but I cant wriite anything, all I can do is close and open Chrome again.

Comment: Please help us help you by reviewing http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/562205/ubuntu-14-10-chrome-doesnt-detect-keyboard-input