# Chrome keyboard does not work

Tags: 14.04

My google chrome that I downloaded on Linux Ubuntu 14.04 after Fifteen words the keyboard no longer works with chrome which I was doing lots of stuff so I lost all my data because I had to go to firefox which in my opinion is not  the best browser. Please Help?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes chromium stops recognizing keystrokes for me, too, especially if I hold down the backspace key. When it does this I run `ibus reset` from command line and it makes it work again. This could work for you too.

There's more information on this page: [Keybord input not work in Chromium 34 Ubuntu 14.04 aura (260972) [using Fcitx would avoid this issue]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449361/keybord-input-not-work-in-chromium-34-ubuntu-14-04-aura-260972-using-fcitx-wo)